# convert from char to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, api

I learn Win API with C++ (I'm newbie). I have problem with character/ string data type.

I also read others docs in google but still don't understand.

Today I meet this problem :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    RECT rect;
    char MyChar = 0;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
        MyChar = LOWORD(wParam);
        MessageBox(hWnd, (LPCWSTR)MyChar, (LPCWSTR)MyChar, MB_OK);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Purpose: Type 1 character and messageBox display it.

My problem is MyChar is a char (8 bits), i want to convert to LPCWSTR. But,... not success.

Anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LPCWSTR is expected to be the address of an array of wide chars (`wchar_t`), and `MessageBox()` expects that array to end in a null character.

You can then use an array with two elements, use the null character in the second one, and modify the first one like this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    RECT rect;
    wchar_t myString[2];
    myString[1] = '\0'; // Ensure the second element is the null char

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
        myString[0] = LOWORD(wParam); // Modify the first element only
        MessageBox(hWnd, myString, myString, MB_OK);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[] = "hello";

WCHAR wsz[64];
swprintf(wsz, L"%S", a);

LPCWSTR p = wsz;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `WM_CHAR`, `wParam` is a UTF-16 code unit -- so, already a value you can store in `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t mystr[2];
mystr[0] = (wchar_t)wParam;
mystr[1] = 0;

MessageBox(hWnd, mystr, mystr, MB_OK);
```

You may want to use `WM_UNICHAR` instead, where `wParam` is a UTF-32 code point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple casting operation, casting the (char*) to (wchar_t*).

Example:

```
char text1[] = "My text vector char";
std::string text2 = "My text std::string";

wchar_t * lpcText1 = (wchar_t *) text1;
wchar_t * lpcText2 = (wchar_t *) text2.c_str();
```